# Cancellation of the account

Tags: account

I set up an account at Salesforce, because our customers have sent me some documents that required the activation of the account. As it turned out, it was a misunderstanding.

When I started the account, I used the 30 trial version. If I don't want to continue using this product, must I to deactivate my account, or my account will be deactivated automatically after 30 days?

Comment: Hi Pavel, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The more details you provide, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer that you'll find helpful. It's unclear to me what account you're trying to cancel and what your actual question is.

Answer (score 0):

I would first recommend you look at the documentation your customers sent you to see if you agreed to something at another time that's part of the documentation.

From Salesforce Help on [Trial Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=getstart.htm),

> During your trial, you can evaluate Salesforce before you subscribe. Your trial includes:
>
> - Sample data. You can delete sample data or start a new trial.
> - Administrator privileges. The person who signed up automatically becomes the administrator. You can add another administrator when you add more users.
> - A variety of Salesforce features.
> - The ability to subscribe to Salesforce.

Unless you provided payment information and actually "subscribed", a trial is exactly that, a "trial" and access to your org will cease at the end of the trial unless you [convert a trial using checkout](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=order_trial.htm).

You can call 1-800-667-6389 for more information.